# How to change the design of the IconButton in material-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, material-ui

Material-ui has provided us with a default icon button. However, I would like to change the design of the default icon button to be like this : [IconButton design needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvkcw.png)

May I know how do I change it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As per [these docs](https://material-ui.com/style/icons/) (see them for detailed instructions), `IconButton` will work with any of the icons [found here](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline). The image you have linked looks most like `menu`. Example of usage:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Menu from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <IconButton>
        <Menu/>
      </IconButton>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If you're using `create-react-app` and want to use a custom SVG, do this:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import CustomMenu from './custom_menu.svg'; // root of src

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <IconButton>
        <img src={CustomMenu}/>
      </IconButton>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what if I want to use a custom made icon button like svg that I made by myself? 
Can I replace the default icon button with my designed button?

Comment: Edited my reply with an example